# dbghelp - Get struct symbol by name

Tags: c++, windbg, symbols, dbghelp

I am building a Symbols service, and I want to be able to print the struct variables and their offsets. I am loading the needed pdb, and trying to find a struct that fits the given mask. For example, I want to get details about the struct `_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION`.

While using `windbg`, I use the command `dt MSVCP120!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION` and I get the struct information (exactly what I want). But, when I search the symbol using my code:

```
SymEnumSymbols(GetCurrentProcess(), base_addr,"MSVCP120!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION", enum_symbols_callback, NULL);

BOOL CALLBACK symbol_processor::enum_symbols_callback(PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo, ULONG SymbolSize, PVOID UserContext)
{
    printf("Name = %s\n", pSymInfo->Name);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Nothing is printed.. Meaning, there is no match for the mask..
This does work when the mask is a function (for example `"MSVCP120!std::tr2::sys::_Open_dir"`)

So, how do I get the symbol of a struct..?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contents of folder prior to compileing

```
:\>ls -l
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0 459 2015-09-10 10:23 structshow.cpp
```

source

```
:\>cat structshow.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment (lib,"dbghelp.lib")
BOOL CALLBACK mycallback(PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo,ULONG,PVOID){
  printf("%s\n",pSymInfo->Name);
  return true;
}
int main(){
  HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryA("c:\\windows\\system32\\ntdll.dll");
  HANDLE hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
  SymInitialize(hproc,"F:\\symbols",TRUE);
  SymEnumTypesByName(hproc,(ULONG64)hmod,"*!_R*",mycallback,0);
  return 0;
}
```

compile using

```
:\>..\compile.bat

:\>if "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\" == "" ()

:\>cl /Zi /EHsc /nologo /W4 /analyze *.cpp /link /RELEASE structshow.cpp

:\>ls -l
```

contents of folder post compiling

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0     459 2015-09-10 10:23 structshow.cpp
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Admin 0   89088 2015-09-10 10:29 structshow.exe
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0   21081 2015-09-10 10:29 structshow.obj
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0 1002496 2015-09-10 10:29 structshow.pdb
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0   94208 2015-09-10 10:29 vc100.pdb
```

use latest dbghelp.dll

```
:\>copy xxxx\dbghelp.dll .
        1 file(s) copied.

:\>echo "do not use system dbghelp.dll it is 
outdated SymbolEnumTypesbyName is available in 
dbghelp version 6.8 and above only "
```

execute compiled binary

```
:\>structshow.exe
_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS
_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION <----------------------
_RTL_STACK_TRACE_ENTRY
_RTL_TRACE_BLOCK
_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
_RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR
_RTL_TRACE_DATABASE
_RTL_TRACE_SEGMENT
```

Comment: Could that be summarized as "You used `MSVCP120!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION` but it should have been `ntdll!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION`"?

Comment: @Thomas It was a good example (msvcp120.dll does include it). But, it could be summarized as "You used `SymEnumSymbols` but it should have been `SymEnumTypesByName`". Stupid me :)

Comment: msvcp120 may hold the symbol i dont know rtl_critical_section symbol type info is held by many modules one of them is ntdll  others being various flavors of ntos as well as mssmbios.sys lkd> dt *!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
          ntkrnlpa!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
          mssmbios!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
          ntdll!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION